# Как запилить решето эратосфена для 10^9 ? или хотя бы для 10^8

Tags: delphi, алгоритм, pascal, математика, простые-числа

Ну, я обычно пишу эратосфена так:

```
p: array [1..maxn] of boolean;
...
procedure erat(n: longint);
var
i, j: longint;
begin
   fillchar(p, sizeof(p), true);
   p[1] := false;
   i := 3;
   while i <= n do
   begin
      if p[i] then
      begin
         j := i+i;
         while j <= n do
         begin
            p[j] := false;
            j := j+i;
         end;
      end;
      i := i+2;
   end;
end;
```

Но дело в том, что 10^9 - это гиг памяти:) Как можно оптимизировать? Или, подскажите, как можно быстро генерировать простые числа до 10^8, хотя бы. Лимит по памяти 65 мб:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Первое, что приходит в голову - это хранить все уже найденые простые числа, и каждое следующее число проверять на делимость на уже найденые:

```
vector<int> primes;
primes.push_back(2);
for (int i = 3; i < 1000000000; ++i) {
    bool isPrime = true;
    for (size_t j = 0; j < primes.size(); ++j) {
         if (!(i % primes[j])) {
             isPrime = false;
             break;
         }
         if (isPrime) primes.push_back(i);
    }
}
```

Но проблема у вас не только в памяти, а еще и во времени работы - этот алгоритм (как и решето Эратосфена) требует порядка N^2 операций (хотя можно небольшим изменением уменьшить сложность до N^(3/2)), поэтому такой алгоритм при N = 10^9 не отработатет ни за какое разумное время.

Comment: уже думал такой вариант, он будет долго работать. Т.к. до 10^7 уже 650.000 простых чисел:)

Comment: Вы правы, буду думать что-то другое:) а можно ли на отрезке как то быстро искать простые числа, т.е. не от 1 до n а пусть от n-1000 до n? или только если в лоб перебирать делители до корня?

Answer (score 6):

уложится в 65 мб можно. Дело в том, что хранить четные числа нет смысла, а начинать хранить с тройки. Также нам не нужно хранить само число, а только признак, а это один бит.
считаем (10^9) / 2 / 8 = 59.6 Мб (ещё немного останется на все про все).
Осталось только научится вычислять место в этом массиве, но думаю справитесь (формально (!!! нужно уточнить) - там нужно разделить на 16, целая часть - номер байта, остаток разделить пополам - номер бита).

**Добавлено.**

где-то так

```
procedure setPrime(a:integer;prime:boolean);
var x,y:integer;
begin
  if a mod 2 = 0 then exit;
  a := a div 2;
  x := a div 8;
  y := a mod 8;
  y := 1 shl y;
  if prime then data[x] := data[x] or y else data[x] := data[x] and not y;
end;
```

и чтение

```
function isPrime(a:integer):boolean;
var x,y:integer;
begin
  result := true;
  if a = 2 exit;
  result := true;
  if a mod 2 = 0 then exit;
  a := a div 2;
  x := a div 8;
  y := a mod 8;
  y := 1 shl y;
  result := data[x] and y;
end;
```

data - это массив на 65мб типа byte:)
Хотя никто не мешает переделать под longint.

Comment: ну я сами числа и не храню, а только признак true или false - 1 байт занимает. а чтобы не тратить память на четные числа можно по подробнее, что вы предлагаете сделать? если не хранить четные числа, то в моем способе это будет 5*10^8 байт. А как хранить один бит?

Comment: хранить 8 чисел в одном байте.

Comment: а как такое можно реализовать?:)

Comment: Добавлено в ответ.

Comment: тут немного подумалось и придумалось, что можно все простые числа до 10^9 упаковать в 18мб (приблизительная оценка).

Comment: а поподробнее можно?

Comment: Да все элементарно просто. Запишем натуральные числа так (по 6 в строку)
 1  2  3  4  5  6
 7  8  9 10 11 12
13 14 15 16 17 18
Несложно доказать, что начиная с второй строки, простых чисел в 2,3,4 и 6 колонке искать не стоит. Только в первой и пятой. Поэтому нужно сохранить таблицу простых до 6 включительно, а дальше только было ли простое в 1 и 5 колонке. Пренебрегая первыми 6 числами, можно утверждать, что в один байт можно вместить 24 числа. Это уже 40Мб на 10^9.
При диапазоне на 30 чисел, простых будет не более 8. Это уже 32Мб.
Если диапазоно 2*3*5*7*11 = 2310, то будет 480 и это 25Мб.

Answer (score 2):

ищите простые числа не до самого n, а до корня из n. дальше их не может быть

Comment: вы уверены? что, например, между 10 и 100 простых чисел нет?

Comment: Видимо, неправильно сформулированный совет. Подозреваю, что имелось ввиду искать делители только до корня с n. На примере:
для 101 надо перебрать простые делители только 2,3,5,7 (< корень(101))

--------------

Обосновывается это тем, что из двух множителей числа один однозначно меньше или равен корню этого числа.

Answer (score 1):

есть недетерминированные тесты простоты, например метод Рабина-Миллера. имеет смысл просто иметь таблицу первых простых чисел какой то размерности, а большие числа проверять вероятностными тестами

Answer (score 0):

В дополнение для большей скорости можно использовать операции shr, shl, and.

```
function isPrime(a:integer):boolean;
var x,y:integer;
begin
  result := true;
  if a and 1 = 0 then exit;
  a := a shr 1;
  x := a shr 3;
  y := 1 shl (a and 8);
  result := data[x] and y;
end;
```

Ератосфена тоже чуть-чуть можно ускорить...

```
p: array [1..maxn] of boolean;
...
procedure erat(n: longint);
var
i, j: longint;
begin
   fillchar(p, sizeof(p), true);
   p[1] := false;
   i := 3; // Наверное всё таки 2...
   while i <= n do
   begin
      while p[i] do inc(i); // Чуть быстрее так как нет лишних переходов
      j := i shl 1;
      while j <= n do
      begin
         p[j] := false;
         inc(j,i);
      end;
      inc(i,2); // А тут inc(i) так как проверка на чётность в isPrime
   end;
end;
```

Comment: Компилятор до этого мог догадаться и сам, если в этом есть выигрыш в скорости=) Тут тот случай, когда надо менять алгоритм, а не пытаться выжать всё из имеющегося.

Comment: Не спорю... =)

Answer (score 0):

Можно улучшить проверку на простоту, к примеру так:

```
bool isPrime(int number) {
    if (number <=0 || 0==number%2)
        return false;

    double d = number;
    int num = static_cast<int>(sqrt(d));
    num -= (1-num%2);

    for (int n=num-1; n>0; n-=2) {
        if(0==(num%n))
            return false
    }
    return true;
}
```

Этим кодом можно чуть улучшить performance при проверке на простоту. Здесь основная соль в использовании sqrt(). Как и почему так работает рекомендую почитать в Коутинхо. Лучше него пояснить у меня не получится ;)