# Решето Эратосфена

Tags: javascript, массивы, алгоритм, математика, простые-числа

Вот код для поиска всех простых чисел до 100 и выведения их суммы.

Объясните, пожалуйста, каким образом числа от 2 до 100 записываются в массив, а также, куда идет число p?

```
var arr = [];

for (var i = 2; i < 100; i++) {
  arr[i] = true
}

var p = 2;

do {
  // шаг 3
  for (i = 2 * p; i < 100; i += p) {
    arr[i] = false;
  }

  // шаг 4
  for (i = p + 1; i < 100; i++) {
    if (arr[i]) break;
  }

  p = i;
} while (p * p < 100); // шаг 5

// шаг 6 (готово)
// посчитать сумму
var sum = 0;
for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  if (arr[i]) {
    sum += i;
  }
}

alert( sum );
```

Comment: Предлагаю вам выступить в роли интерпретатора JS и самостоятельно пройти весь алгоритм. Листа бумаги хватит, чтобы записать итоговый массив и все промежуточные значения счетчиков.

Comment: [на картинку полезно посмотреть, чтобы понять как алгоритм работает (`false` означает крестик в данном случае)](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE_%D0%AD%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%84%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0#.D0.90.D0.BB.D0.B3.D0.BE.D1.80.D0.B8.D1.82.D0.BC)

Answer (score 7):

> Объясните, пожалуйста каким образом числа от 2 до 100 записываются в массив,

Используется массив `boolean`, в котором (после окончания работы алгоритма) `i`-й элемент равен `true` тогда и только тогда, когда число `i` – простое.

> а также куда идет число `p`?

В нем хранится последнее найденное простое число. Когда мы его находим, то вычеркиваем из массива все числа, кратные `p`, то есть `p`, `2p`, `3p`...

Обратите внимание на связанный вопрос об оптимизации этого алгоритма для больших N: [Как запилить решето эратосфена для 10^9 ? или хотя бы для 10^8](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/56990/181472)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

<sup>Изображение: [Wikipedia](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE_%D0%AD%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%84%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0#/media/File:New_Animation_Sieve_of_Eratosthenes.gif), лицензия [GNU Free Documentation License](http://www.gnu.org/copyleft/fdl.html). [Спасибо jfs за ссылку](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/439414/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%AD%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%84%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0/439418#comment460638_439414)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

Судя по коду числа в массив не записываются, в массив записываются флаги.
Сначала

```
for (var i = 2; i < 100; i++) {
  arr[i] = true
}
```

все элементы массива со 2го по 100й помечаются истиной.
Потом в двойном цикле

```
do {
  // шаг 3
  for (i = 2 * p; i < 100; i += p) {
    arr[i] = false;
  }
...
```

вычеркиваются кратные.

И в конце уже элементы массива используются в условие при подсчете

```
  if (arr[i]) {
      sum += i;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы получить Решето Эратосфена до 100, достаточно вычеркнуть простые делители <10: **2,3,5,7** (как показал [Nick Volynkin](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/181472/nick-volynkin)).
А если нужно что-то помасштабней, то Вам [сюда](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/24957/%D0%9D%D0%B0%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8B%D1%85-%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BB-%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%AD%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%84%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0/471155#471155)