# Как бессмысленное изменение оператора проверки влияет на скорость кода Cython?

Tags: python, производительность, cython

У меня есть следующие два варианта кода для Cython:

Вариант 1:

```
cpdef prime(int n):
    cdef int i
    if n < 2: return False
    for i in xrange(3, int(n**0.5) + 2, 2):
        if not n % i: return False
    return True
```

Вариант 2:

```
cpdef prime(int n):
    cdef int i
    if n < -1: return False
    for i in xrange(3, int(n**0.5) + 2, 2):
        if not n % i: return False
    return True
```

Как видно, единственная разница в строке:

```
if n < -1: return False
```

Вызывается один из вариантов этого кода из Python самым обычным образом:

```
for i in xrange(10000):
    result = prime(1007963447)
```

Проверяю только на этом числе, никаких n < 2, а тем более n < -1.

Время выполнения для каждого варианта:

```
Вариант 1: 1.20464787483
Вариант 2: 0.90665817260
```

- Если заменить строку `if n < 2: return False` на `if False: return`
  или `if n < 0: pass`, время выполнения опять возрастает до ~1.10sec.
- Если заменить на `if n < 0: return False` или `if n < 0: return`, то
  время выполнения не меняется (~0.9sec).
- Если вообще убрать эту строку, то время выполнения возрастает до
  ~1.10sec.

Пробовал разные варианты. Среда разработки, кодировки и фазы луны не влияют на результат, влияет только эта строка.

Вопрос: почему такие бессмысленные изменения ускоряют\змедляют работу кода? Или я чего-то не понимаю?

UPD. Вот наглядная разница в сгенерированных файлах "*.c": [Diff Online](https://www.diffnow.com/?report=7h5km)

Единственная разница в соответствующих строках:

```
pyx_t_1 = ((__pyx_v_n < -1) != 0);
```

и

```
pyx_t_1 = ((__pyx_v_n < 2) != 0);
```

UPD2. Также добавил сравнение ассемблерных листингов (слева n<2): [Assembler listing](https://www.diffnow.com/?report=nqu8d)

Comment: попробуйте посмотреть полученный C-код

Comment: @dizballanze, хорошая идея. Добавил разницу между сгенерированными файлами.

Comment: Возможно, компилятор как-то оптимизирует код, предполагая, что если по условию n<2 происходит выход, то в цикл попадают только положительные n. Попробуйте вывести ассемблерный листинг и сравнить )

Comment: что происходит, если использовать `unsigned` тип для `n`, `i`?

Comment: в сторону: если необходимо отфильтровать простые числа из какого-либо диапазона, то можно использовать [решето Эратосфена](https://goo.gl/5eaYRj) -- [простой](http://stackoverflow.com/a/193605/4279) и эффективный алгоритм (или для больших чисел решето Аткина). Если отдельные числа хочется проверить, то [Тест Миллера — Рабина](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82_%D0%9C%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0_%E2%80%94_%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0) является эффективным решением.

Comment: @jfs, тогда время выполнения варианта с `n < 2` вырастает до 1.2 sec, если вообще убрать эту проверку, то время не меняется (1.2 sec).
Но есть большая странность при использовании такого типа. Условие `n < -1` почему-то возвращает True и функция дальше не отрабатывает. Проверял, если после этого условия вывести в консоль значение `n`, то оно как и должно быть, равно 1007963447.

Comment: @jfs, спасибо большое! Хоть и в сторону, но для меня полезно.

Comment: `n < -1`: Не следует сравнивать `unsigned` и `int`. Следует явно типы указать. `<unsigned>-1` может быть большим положительным числом (UINT_MAX).

Comment: @jfs, возможно это глупость, но объявил `cdef unsigned lim = -1` и поменял условие на `n < lim` - результат тот-же, условие выполняется :\ (использование `<unsigned>-1` тоже ничего не поменяло).
Хотел понять одну странность, а нашел ещё и вторую.

Comment: Это не странность, а ожидаемо для C: `<unsigned>-1` выражение определено: `-1 + (UINT_MAX + 1) == UINT_MAX` [§6.3.1.3/2](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf)

Comment: @insolor, добавил листинги. Только вот я в них ничего не понимаю.

Comment: А если то же число (аргумент) ввести с клавиатуры?

Comment: @Qwertiy, вы имеете в виду переменную `n`? Или то, с чем она сравнивается?

Comment: Я имею в виду `n`. Вдруг он её тоже как-то в оптимизации использует?

Comment: @Qwertiy, исключено, так как cython компилирует отдельную библиотеку, а вызывающий её код находится в обычном python-скрипте, которого до компиляции может и не существовать.

Comment: Как тут уже сказали, `-1` может разворачиваться в большое число, для которого используется многобайтовая не быстрая арифметика, возможно для избежания такой ситуации имеет смысл записать условие следующим образом? `if n+1 < 0: return False`

Comment: Ещё вариант оптимизации: хранить найденные простые числа и проверять делимость на них. [Как запилить решето эратосфена для 10^9 ? или хотя бы для 10^8](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/56992)

Comment: @dsnk, хорошо, это я уже более или менее понял. Но вот почему тогда такая конструкция `if n+1 < 0: return False` ускоряет выполнение функции. Если убрать её - замедлится.

Comment: @anatolii Это установленный факт или домыслы? Если факт, это особенности оптимизации компилятора.

Comment: @dsnk, я же написал об этом в вопросе. Это результат моих экспериментов.
Да, это оптимизация. Суть в том, что я бы хотел в последствии использовать её для ускорения. Для этого её нужно понять.

Comment: @anatolii Это правильно, и тут понадобиться изучать результаты компиляции, сравнивая их. Но они могут отличаться для разных компиляторов и даже для одного компилятора, при использовании различных опций.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещен в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29364/discussion-on-question-by-anatolii-----).

Answer (score 27, accepted):

В этом вопросе сразу бросается в глаза то, что на результаты бенчмарка влияет константа, работающая за пределами цикла. При наличии цикла, длинной около sqrt(1007963447), ничто за его пределами не должно сколь-нибудь заметно влиять на результат (код довольно прозрачен и возможные сторонние эффекты почти исключены).

Я провел небольшое расследование и обнаружил что ассемблерные листинги обоих версий довольно сильно отличаются как раз внутри цикла на месте операции взятия остатка деления. Вместо двух инструкций в быстрой версии:

```
idivl   %esi
testl   %edx, %edx
```

В медленной версии присутствует целый кусок кода:

```
idivl   %esi
movl    %edx, %esi
xorl    %ecx, %esi
shrl    $31, %esi
testl   %edx, %edx
setne   %dil
andl    %edi, %esi
imull   %ecx, %esi
addq    $2, %rcx
addl    %esi, %edx
```

Среди прочего тут присутствует относительно "тяжелая" операция умножения `imull`. Видимо, именно этот кусок ответственен за разницу в скоростях на бенчмарке. На  появление этого куска влияет значение константы с которой в исходнике сравнивается переменная `n` совсем в другом месте, выше по тексту за пределами цикла.

Вот что я выяснил:

Интересное поведение компилятора является следствием действия нескольких факторов:

1. Особенность работы оператора `%` на python. Он призван обеспечивать тождество `x == (x//y)*y + (x%y)`, то есть знак частного соответствует знаку делителя (второго операнда), что противоречит стандарту C. Такое поведение не просто реализуется на x86 архитектуре и на каждую инструкцию `idiv` приходится вставлять дополнительный код на проверку отритцательных операндов и корректировку результата. Cython поумолчанию также следует "питоновому" стандарту.
2. Особенность генерации кода Cython, при которой простые арифметические операции в некоторых случаях реализованы как inline фунций, что, впрочем, не сильно сказывается на производительности по причине (3). Например, "питоновое" взятие остатка деления реализовано через вызов `__Pyx_mod_int`.
3. На этапе компиляции в машинный код происходит чудо: Мощный оптимизатор gcc снасначала раскручивает inline фунции, потом анализирует все условия и перерассчитывает типы данных и математические области определения каждой переменной на каждой ветке алгоритма. Например, переменная `n` объявленная в коде как `int`, после прохождения ветвления на условии `if (n < 0) return;` дальше становится ограниченной областью определения `[0; INT_MAX]`, т.е. фактически беззнаковой. При выполнении инструкции `idiv` область определения частного и остатка также можно рассчитать зная области определения делимого и делителя. Остаток, в нашем случае, также попадает в `[0; INT_MAX]` и все дальнейшие проверки на неотрицательность и идущие от них ветки алгоритма просто удаляются как unreachable code. В `__Pyx_mod_int` происходит как раз такая проверка с последующий корректировкой остатка (в случае отрицательного). Поэтому наличие/отсутствие всего этого куска в скомпилированном коде полностью зависит от значения константы с которой сравнивается переменная `n` выше по тексту. Условие `n >= -1` не гарантирует неотрицательности остатка и проверка/корректировка из `__Pyx_mod_int` выполняется, но `n >= 0` - гарантирует неотрицательность и функция взятия остатка сводится почти к одной инструкции процессора - `idiv`.

Хорошей новостью является то, что поведение Cython в отношении следования "питоновым" стандартам деления и взятия остатка можно легко переопределить. Для этого надо поставить декоратор `@cython.cdivision(True)` перед функцией или в сверху в заголовке модуля (перед первой строкой) вставить:

```
#!python
#cython: cdivision=True
```

Можно замерить скорость и убедится, что в этом случае остаток деления будет работает одинаково быстро вне зависимости от контекста. Операция `%` будет вести себя по С стандарту, компилироваться в одну процессорную инструкцию и `__Pyx_mod_int` не будет даже появляться в `*.c` исходниках на выходе Cython-компиляции.

Подробнее об этом от авторов Cython можно почитать в  [CEP 516 - Division Semantics](https://github.com/cython/cython/wiki/enhancements-division).

Comment: Отличное исследование, особенно для первого ответа!

Comment: кратко: Cython реализует Python  семантику для `%` ([modulo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation)), которая компилируется в неэффективный код по сравнению с C `%` ([remainder](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1907565/4279)). Для положительных чисел обе операции совпадают и gcc способен сгенерировать эффективный код. gcc "умный" и `if n < 2: return False` (С аналог) перед циклом достаточны для него чтобы определить что `n` всегда положительно и поэтому генерируется быстрый код. `if n < -1: return False` разрешает отрицательные значения и поэтому медленный  более общий код генерируется.

Answer (score 2):

Рекомендую использовать модуль dis для получения байт-кода Пайтон.
https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/dis.html
В нем Вы увидите разницу, я полагаю. Само собой оптимизация может проходить и на стадии компиляции при одинаковом байт-коде Пайтон.

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?